# Value Not Changing

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

In my Project I am Checking some conditions if it is true the action will Occur otherwise the Error message will be shown in the Label during the runtime.

My problem is that when the condition fails the cursor goes to the else block and the code also get Excecuted but the text of the Label is not changed.What could be the Problem?

The Condition part is,

```
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0 
                && DateTime.Parse(frmtxtdt.Text).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") == DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() 
                && DateTime.Parse(totxtdt.Text).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")  == DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString())
            {
                ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Passkeys";

                ds.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/XMLReports/_Passkeys.xml"));
                string filename = Server.MapPath("~/Upload/Pkey_rpt.rpt");
                rpt.Load(filename);
                rpt.SetDataSource(ds);
                rpt.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, true, "Passkeys");

            }
            else if(frmtxtdt.Text.Trim() !=null && totxtdt.Text.Trim()!=null)
            {
                if (DateTime.Parse(frmtxtdt.Text).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")   == DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() 
                     && DateTime.Parse(totxtdt.Text).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") == DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() 
                     && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
                {

                    lblmsg.Text = "Pass Key Not Yet Delivered for the Selected Date...";
                    //The value(lblmsg.Text) not Changing when comes here.
                }
                else
                {

                    lblmsg.Text = "There is No Schedule for the Selected date....";
                    //The value(lblmsg.Text) not Changing when comes here.

                }

            }

        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
```

Friends My problem is not about [Datetime] or [Datetime Picker] it is that, The text of the label is Changing at runtime but not dispalying.

And also in the [rpt.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, true, "Passkeys");
] Crystal Report Generator in PDF file format the Report is Loading and there is also data in XML file but it is not Converted into PDF file for Download.

Comment: Why are you comparing dates using string comparisons? It would be *much* better to parse the input textual data, then do everything else using `DateTime` values.

Comment: Perhaps the label is overwritten later on?

Comment: @ Jon Skeet I am comparing dates using string comparisions because the Selected date will in text format in the Textbox

Comment: @ Erno I also tried with a  `Clientmessaging` Function the same result as label

Comment: @Rajesh - If the text represents `DateTime`, then parse it as soon as possible and only work with that. But even disregarding that, if you want to compare the strings, then compare the strings. Parsing it to `DateTime` and then `ToString()` it back is redundant if you don't want to work with `DateTime` (which you *should* want to!).

Comment: where do you place your code in page_load or click events

Comment: Put a conditional breakpoint on the label so you'll know when it changes

Comment: @Corak I don't want to work with Full `Datetime` because I want only `Date` part of it thats why I am Parsing it and converting it to String

Comment: Why do you have `catch { throw; }` at the end? It's redundant.

Comment: That's what [DateTime.Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) is for.

Comment: @Rajesh, your code will be hellishly buggy if you try and use it on an American database, try DateTime.TryParse with the overload that includes an injected format provider and the date time styles arguments...

Comment: @ Corak the `Datetime.Date` returns `06/10/2013 12:00 AM`

Comment: @ R Square Some in Functions and Some in Click events Why ?

Comment: As does `DateTime.Today`. So when you compare the two, they should be equal.

Comment: @ Erno I had placed a Breakpoint and checked. The Text of the Label is Changing but not Displaying

Comment: @ Corak Ok I May change the Conditions, but what about the Exact Problem _The Text of Label is Changing during runtime but not Displaying_

Comment: @ Marcelo Cantos I had Changed it  as `catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblmsg.Text = ex.Message;
            }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the context of the error, Web or desktop?
The alternatives may be:

- If you are using any component to make an AJAX call this label is not within the content being sent to the server and it is not updated. (Web Only)
- You may be experiencing some event (postback) that is clearing the value of this label (Web Only)
- Check the visible property of the label, it may be being altered in some part of the code
- Make sure the color of the label is not the same color as the background of your screen, believe it can happen.
- Any component is overlapping this label or that label is the location / position outside the form

Comment: @ renefc3
  Mine is a We Application I had Check the I added one more condition `if(!IsPostback)` and also check the color and the Visible properties all are correct

Comment: Rajesh, Have you ever tried to change the value of another control on the same point (because if it works, it eliminates some options)?
would like a broader context of their application to try to simulate the problem, for example, the C # page?
This makes it easier to help

Answer (score 0):

Also, if You don't know there are very handy controls, that are called "DateTimePicker", that are specifically created for choosing Dates. You should give them a try.

I wonder if you get an exception somewhere before the change?

Comment: @ Andrey I am Sure that it is not Date Picker Problem the Text of the Label is Changing but Not displaying

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the UI thread is too loaded

Add `lblmsg.Refresh();` after setting the text

if it doesn't work move the method to background thread; beware of the cross threading though. For simple interthread operations you can use ReportProgress method of BackgroundWorker Class

Comment: @ Peuczyński
  I cant use `lblmsg.Refresh();` it is showing the error `System.Web.UI.Webcontrols.lblmsg.Refresh(); does not exist R U missing a Assembley or Reference`

Comment: You didn't mention that this is WebUI. You change the label using Text property so I ruled out WPF (label.Content) and figured it's Winforms not ASP.NET in which I don't have much experience, but moving to background thread should actually work. Also take a look at sth called Asynchronous Pages in ASP

Answer (score 0):

I may assume that you have some watcher associated with changing values of Text fields of your labels, - so when changing text in your labels code block in this handler fails (or works fine, but doesn't assume changing actual value of label text), updating text fails.